# Big O of Recursive Methods

Tags: recursion, big-o

I'm having difficulty determining the big O of simple recursive methods. how can I calculate big-O for these methods?

Case 1) find big-O for method f:

```
int f(int x){
    if(x<1) return 1;
    return f(x-1)+g(x);
}

int g(int x){
    if(x<2) return 1;
    return f(x-1)+g(x/2);
}
```

Case 2)

```
int test(int n){
    if(x<=2) return 1;
    return test(n-2) * test(n-2);
}
```

Case 3)

```
int T(int n){
    if(n<=1) return 1;
    return T(n/2)+T(n/2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1**

Setting the base cases aside (`g(1) = g(0) = 1`, etc.), you can rewrite `g` in terms of `f`:

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + g(n) <=> g(n) = f(n)-f(n-1)
```

We know that `g` is defined as:

```
g(n) = f(n-1) + g(n/2)
```

If we replace `g(n/2)` with the rewritten form above, we get:

```
g(n) = f(n-1) + f(n/2) + f(n/2-1)
```

Which means that we can rewrite `f` without any reference to `g`, by replacing `g(n)` in the original definition of `f` with the formula above:

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-1) + f(n/2) + f(n/2-1)
```

To double check that this is equivalent, you can run this program, which accepts an integer `n` as the first argument, and prints the result of the original `f(n)` followed by the rewritten form of `f(n)` (called `f2` in the code):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int g(int x);

int f(int x) {
    if (x < 1)
        return 1;
    return f(x-1)+g(x);
}

int g(int x) {
    if (x < 2)
        return 1;
    return f(x-1)+g(x/2);
}

int f2(int x) {
    if (x < 1)
        return 1;
    return f2(x-1)+f2(x-1)+f2(x/2)-f2(x/2-1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", f(n));
    printf("%d\n", f2(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Some examples:

```
$ ./a.out 10
1952
1952
$ ./a.out 11
3932
3932
$ ./a.out 12
7923
7923
$ ./a.out 13
15905
15905
$ ./a.out 14
31928
31928
$ ./a.out 15
63974
63974
```

Now, if you imagine the recursion tree, each node branches off into 4 sub-trees (one for each of `f(n-1)`, `f(n-1)`, `f(n/2)` and `f(n/2-1)`). The size of each subtree is not the same, e.g., if we descend on a sub-tree and always follow any of the 2 rightmost branches, we have a binary tree of depth `log(N)`. But there are other branches (if we always follow the `f(n-1)` path) that have depth `n`, and it branches into `n-1` twice. Because of this, we can say it's definitely exponential.

It's a bit hard to get the exact number, but an obvious upper bound is `O(4^N)` - though this disregards the fact that some branches are only `log(N)` deep, so in reality it's a bit better than `O(4^N)`.

**Case 2**

Think about the recursion tree again. At each point, we branch twice (`test(n-2)` and `test(n-2)`). Because we decrease `n` by 2 on each call, the tree will be `O(n/2)` deep, so we need `O(2^(n/2))` time to traverse the tree - again, an exponential growth. Not particularly interesting.

(Side note: if you were to use memoization here, this would be linear!).

**Case 3**

Similar logic as case 2, but this time the tree has depth `log(N)` (because that's how many times you need to divide `N` by 2 to get to the base case), so we get `2^log(N) = N`. So it's linear.